# Android SeekBar within a homescreen Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, seekbar

I am looking to find a way to add a `SeekBar` to a homescreen widget. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010513/is-it-possible-to-make-a-home-screen-widget-that-contains-a-seekbar) post on StackOverflow, I found that SeekBar's are not supported within a RemoteView, because it is a descendant of a `ProgressBar`. (Descendants of the accepted widgets are not supported)

Though, in my project, I am using Lars Werkman's `HoloColorPicker` found [here](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker). If you notice in the src, his `OpacityBar` (which is essentially a SeekBar) extends a `View`. Since all the accepted widgets ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)) are descendants of `View`, I would think this would work. But alas, upon trying to load the homescreen widget with the `OpacityBar`, it shows up with the "Problem loading widget" response.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? And know how to make it work?

Or does anyone know how to get a working `SeekBar` within a homescreen widget?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since all the accepted widgets (here) are descendants of View, I would think this would work

I have no idea why you conclude that, as it it is a logical fallacy. According to your logic, since negative numbers are types of number, all numbers are negative.

> Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Because you cannot use custom `View`s, or anything else not supported by `RemoteViews`, in an app widget.

> And know how to make it work?  Or does anyone know how to get a working SeekBar within a homescreen widget?

Write your own home screen, and implement whatever you are trying to do with the `SeekBar` in that custom home screen.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Are you referring me to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)?

Comment: @BarryBostwick: "Are you referring me to do something like this?" -- in the third paragraph of my answer, yes.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the solution I am looking for. A better question may be: if you look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hinterhofapps.sliderwidget&hl=en), each button in the homescreen widget opens a pop-up with a `SeekBar` in it. Do you know what it is doing underneath to make this work?

Comment: @BarryBostwick: That is a dialog-themed activity, in all likelihood. IIRC, there's an extra that is passed along with the `Intent` used to start your activity when it is launched from an app widget, which contains some coordinate details of where the app widget was on the screen, for positioning purposes.